# How do you specify image path using App Inventor Java Bridge library for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app-inventor

Note: The library I have to use can be downloaded from here:
http://www.appinventor.org/jBridgeIntro

I'm currently working on a project in which we have to make an app using the App Inventor Java Bridge Library. I'm trying to add an image to a button (App Inventor Button, not google widget) but I can't seem to get the image to display. I've tried multiple formats for image-paths but nothing seems to work. I have the images saved as .png files and I have them in the drawable folder.

The App Inventor Button sets the Image using this (eg.):

```
myButton.Image("path of image");
```

But I can't find out what format `.Image()` expects the file path to be in.

I have no errors other than E/ButtonBase: Unable to load 'filepath'. I have no problems setting the background color or the font size or any other methods associated with an App Inventor Button in Java. It's just Image file paths that seem to be holding the project up.

I've tried:
`"myimage.png"`,
`"R.drawable.myimage.png"`,
`"\res\drawable\myimage.png"`and so on. Nothing seems to work.

This problem seems to happen with Image referencing in general in this library, whether it's a button/canvas/arrangement etc.

Does anybody have any ideas on what format it actually needs to be in?

(Note: If anyone has any code sample from this Library, related or unrelated to this question. It could help me better understand the library and solve this issue.)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was create an "assets" folder in `src/main` to store any assets required by the app and as soon as I did that I could just use `"myImage.png"`